# Create custom notifications for android app

Tags: android, notifications

In my app i want to diaplay the notifications. A background service will get the notifications if there are any and then a small tab like in facebook notifications for iphone will come up from bottom and display the notifications.

On click of the notifications tab user will be navigated to the notifications scree.

I am not able to think which feature to use here and how? Please help.

Also please note that i donot want to display this in notification in notification bar but a custom notification within my app only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This feature is called [Notification](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html).

Then you can use it like this:

```
mManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourActivity.class);

Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, "Notify", System.currentTimeMillis());

notification.setLatestEventInfo(YourClass.this, "App Name","Description of the notification", PendingIntent.getActivity(this.getBaseContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT));

mManager.notify(APP_ID, notification);
```

Ok in your edit I see that you want to have a notifaction service only for your app. But then I don't understand this sentence:

> On click of the notifications tab user
>   will be navigated to the notifications
>   screen.

What should happen if the user clicks on your notification? Should really the native notification screen be displayed? Or should it switch back to the application? But you're already in this application since you're using a custom notification.

However I would just use a UI element at the bottom, that is always there but not visible. As soon as you have to create a new notification I would set the text of this UI element accordingly and make it visible. When the user clicks on the UI element, it again gets invisible. Using this approach you don't need a background service and all the other stuff.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. By that sentence I mean I just want to navigate the user to the screen where users can see the complete list of notifications that is a different activity which displays these notifications. But the normal scenario would be that whenever there's an any event a notification count should be displayed below with the text "<Number> Notifications" and it does not matter if he is on any other screen.

Comment: @Bir Ok now I understand it. But it doesn't really change anything in my suggestion. You just have to keep all your displayed notification in a list and instead of showing the notification text int the UI element you show the list size.

Comment: Thanks i will try it out today and confirm.